# multiple targets with one and only one different localisation each

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, target

My project has 6 targets to one source code base. The 6 targets are different programs with different content thanks to different pre-processor statements.

I defined 2 localisations which are French and English.

BUT 4 of the programs should be French only and 2 should be English only.

At the moment, I get French and English for all 6 programs.

How do I remove english from the 4 French programs and french from the 2 English programs please?

I tried target memberships but checking the boxes are the same for either the Localizable.strings (french ) and the localizable.strings (english).
Also if I try to uncheck a localisation for a target, it tries to delete it...
So either I am not doing correctly or I just don't know how to do it

Thanks in advance for any help

Cheers,
geebee

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? This is exactly my predicament.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this ; so for completion in the main.m file:

```
  // ---- target 1 app 1
#ifdef target1_VERSION

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fr", nil]
                                              forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
#endif

    // ---- target 2 app 2
#ifdef target2_VERSION

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil]
                                              forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
#endif
```